# Найти производную от функции

Tags: c++, математика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать класс с функцией реализующей производную функции вида:
[image: функция]

так, чтобы **a** являлась полем-массивом класса. Так же функцию вычисляющую саму f(x)

Вот то, что я смог написать:

```cpp
class Polynom {
private:
    double x, *a;
    int a_size;

public:
    Polynom(double &x, double *a, int &a_size) : x(x), a(a), a_size(a_size) { }
    double getf() {
      double result = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < a_size; k++)
        result += a[k]*cos(k*x);
      return result;
    }
    
    double getderiv(){

    }
};
```

Comment: производная суммы - это сумма производных. производная от `m*cos(kx)` это `-k*m*sin(kx)`, если я не забыл школьную программу. Что делать? да просто перемножить ak на k и взять с минусом. Думаю, то  не сложно.

Comment: как я понял должно получиться что-то вроде такого? for (int k = 0; k < a_size; k++)
        result += -k * a[k] * sin(k*x)

Comment: Вот только что Вам нужно сделать? распечатать производную или вычислить ее значение? если значение - то да, наверно все так и должно быть

Comment: А если нужно распечатать, то как вообще примерно, хотя-бы такое можно сделать? Не очень просто понимаю что имеется ввиду, под напечатать

Comment: в цикле распечатать коэффициенты?

Comment: Оформи свой первый комментарий как ответ. Очень выручил, спасибо большое

Comment: В классе `Polynom` елемент `double x;` - не в тему. Он должен быть аргументом функционального оператора `double operator()(double x)` в замен `double getf()`

Comment: Аргументы в конструктор очень требовательные `Polynom(double &x, double *a, int &a_size)` - они принимают **только** переменные и только не константные. Надо изменить на передачу по-значению `Polynom(double x, double *a, int a_size)`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Спасибо тебе огромное за совет, с перегрузкой оператора действительно становиться вес нереально удобно и просто. Не мог бы подсказать где можно прочитать про конструктор (о том что ты говорил про аргументы)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Производная суммы - это сумма производных. Производная от `m*cos(kx)` это `-k*m*sin(kx)`. Что делать? да просто перемножить ak на k и взять с минусом.

Дальше все зависит от того, что именно хотят в задаче. Если просто распечатать коэффициенты/формулу, то это просто

```
for (int k = 0; k < a.size(); k++) {
    if (k != 0) std::cout << " + ";
    std::cout << -k*a[k] << "*sin(" << k << "x)";
}
```

Если же посчитать значение, то это ещё проще.